# How do I get the index of the array for a job in a batch job that was started using a map distribution in a step function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

I have a script in batch job that gets the index of the batch array using the environment variable like this:

```
import os

# get index of array
int_idx_array = int(os.environ['AWS_BATCH_JOB_ARRAY_INDEX'])
print(f'Array index: {int_idx_array}')
```

This works perfectly unless I run the batch job in a step function using a map distribution in which I get an error because that environment variable does not exist.

My step function is able to start the necessary number of batch jobs but they all fail due to this exception.

Here is my definition:

```
{
  "Comment": "Shared Jobs State Machine",
  "StartAt": "GetListOfFeatures",
  "States": {
    "GetListOfFeatures": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:function:lambda-list-starting-feats-function-ae",
      "Next": "Tuning"
    },
    "Tuning": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:job-queue/queue-batch-tuning-ae-image-1",
        "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:job-definition/job-def-batch-tuning-ae-image-1:1",
        "JobName": "job-name-batch-tuning-ae-image-1",
        "ArrayProperties": {
          "Size": 10
        }
      },
      "Next": "ConcatTuning"
    },
    "ConcatTuning": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:job-queue/queue-batch-concattuning-ae-image-1",
        "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:job-definition/job-def-batch-concattuning-ae-image-1:1",
        "JobName": "job-name-batch-concattuning-ae-image-1",
        "ArrayProperties": {
          "Size": 10
        }
      },
      "Next": "Map"
    },
    "Map": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "DISTRIBUTED",
          "ExecutionType": "STANDARD"
        },
        "StartAt": "SensitivityAnalysis",
        "States": {
          "SensitivityAnalysis": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
            "Parameters": {
              "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:job-definition/job-def-batch-sensitivity-ae-image-5:1",
              "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:job-queue/queue-batch-sensitivity-ae-image-5",
              "JobName": "job-name-batch-sensitivity-ae-image-1"
            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "Label": "Map",
      "MaxConcurrency": 1000,
      "ItemReader": {
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::s3:getObject",
        "ReaderConfig": {
          "InputType": "CSV",
          "CSVHeaderLocation": "FIRST_ROW"
        },
        "Parameters": {
          "Bucket": "20230321-step-functions-poc",
          "Key": "ae/01_list_of_starting_features/df_cols_in_model.csv"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am reading a .csv file from s3 with the number of rows being equal to the number of batch jobs that need to be ran. How do I access the index information from this .csv file?

I also have it saved as a json with the keys being a string index (i.e., "0"). Is it easier to use this?

Answer (score 0):

StepFunctions Map does not submit a Batch array job request unless you define the `ArrayProperties` parameter, as you did earlier in the Step Function Tasks state definitions. The environment variable is not defined since Map is submitting basic jobs. You can confirm this by going to the Batch console and looking at a job that was started from the Map task.